# Text variables of frame's properties in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

How do I create text variables of a frame's width and height then insert them as the text? Or is it possible to do that?

Comment: Frames are *not* text. Text variables are for *text* as the name implies.

Comment: Maybe I would give the problem more specifically. I want determine one of Object Frame's size. Then add them inside the Frame or another Frame as text contents. Actually, I can read the digits from the panels then type them manually. I just want a way automatically.  Thanks!

Comment: you need a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rather basic script.
Returned values are based on object bounds, meaning that if you run it on a rotated object, returned values will be different than the ones in your Transform panel.
Also, it includes strokes. If you want to exclude them, just change line 5     visibleBounds to geometricBounds;

```
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var myDocument = app.documents[0];
    var mySelection = myDocument.selection[0];
    var myPage = mySelection.parentPage;
    var VB = mySelection.visibleBounds;
    var mySelectionHeight = VB[2] - VB[0];
    var mySelectionWidth = VB[3] - VB[1];
    var myTextFrame = myPage.textFrames.add({
        geometricBounds: [VB[0], VB[1], VB[2], VB[3]]
    });

    if (app.selection.length == 0) {
        alert("Select something");
    } else {
        myTextFrame.contents = "Height = " + mySelectionHeight + " \rWidth = " + mySelectionWidth;
        myTextFrame.fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
    }

} else {
    alert("Open a document");
}
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the script is *not* live – the text variable won't automagically rewrite itself while the targeted frame is being resized.

Comment: Good point! Seemed obvious to me, but maybe not to OP

Comment: It is great! It works for me. Can I ask one more question? How can I get this properties you write here like the "my.Selection.visibleBounds". I want to learn how to write these scripts.

Comment: @decode that's great! Scripting has a important learning curve but what you can achieve at the end can be amazing. Now, I'm a lousy scripter so I won't be the one who will give the best advices, but I would recommend starting by learning JavaScript basics. I think "how to get started in indesign scripting" would be a great question (maybe it exists already).